# запрос из нескольких таблиц mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

есть таблицы mysql:

```
|------
|Столбец|Тип|Null|По умолчанию
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|Нет|
|parent_id|int(11)|Нет|0
|title|varchar(255)|Нет|
|description|varchar(255)|Нет|
|keywords|varchar(255)|Нет|
|category_img|varchar(255)|Нет|
|seo|varchar(255)|Нет|
```

|---

```
---
|Столбец|Тип|Null|По умолчанию
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|Нет|
|id_user|int(11)|Нет|
|id_category|int(11)|Нет|
|id_town|int(11)|Нет|
|id_region|int(11)|Нет|
|id_street|int(11)|Нет|
|home_post|varchar(255)|Нет|
|id_album|int(11)|Нет|0
|id_news|int(11)|Нет|0
|title|varchar(255)|Нет|
|title_seo|varchar(255)|Нет|
|descriotion|varchar(255)|Нет|
|img_company|varchar(255)|Нет|
|house|varchar(32)|Нет|
|text|text|Нет|
|schedule|varchar(255)|Нет|
|pause|varchar(255)|Нет|
|day_off|varchar(255)|Нет|
|contacts|varchar(255)|Нет|
|email_company|varchar(255)|Нет|
|url_company|varchar(255)|Нет|
|valid_status|int(1)|Нет|0

|------
|Столбец|Тип|Null|По умолчанию
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|Нет|
|id_town|int(11)|Нет|
|name|varchar(32)|Нет|
== Дамп данных таблицы region

|Столбец|Тип|Null|По умолчанию
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|Нет|
|id_company|int(11)|Нет|
|id_user|int(11)|Нет|
|title|varchar(255)|Нет|
|text|text|Нет|
|reiting|int(11)|Нет|
== Дамп данных таблицы rewards


|------
|Столбец|Тип|Null|По умолчанию
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|Нет|
|name|varchar(32)|Нет|
|lastname|varchar(32)|Нет|
|secondname|varchar(32)|Нет|
|user_type|varchar(2)|Нет|
|login|varchar(32)|Нет|
|pass|varchar(32)|Нет|
|about|text|Нет|
|user_img|varchar(255)|Нет|
|contacts|varchar(255)|Нет|
|id_town|int(11)|Нет|
|id_region|int(11)|Нет|
|id_street|int(11)|Нет|
|home|varchar(32)|Нет|
|email|varchar(64)|Нет|
|link|varchar(255)|Нет|
|link2|varchar(255)|Нет|
|date_registration|varchar(14)|Нет|
|online_status|tinyint(1)|Нет|0
|valid_status|tinyint(4)|Нет|
== Дамп данных таблицы users
```

как правильно создать запрос чтоб из всех этих таблиц выводились в одной таблице все поля о компании названия города улицы, региона, и подсчет количества строк у компании?

Comment: Используйте JOIN, или (и) LEFT JOIN, или (и) GROUP_CONCAT, или (и) субзапросы. Последние не стоит недооценивать, зачастую они хорошо оптимизируются, особенно, если индексы под это выстроены.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      `rewards`.*,
      `users`.`id` as `id`,
      `category`.`id` AS `id_category`,
      `users`.`name` as `user_name`,
      `users`.`last_name` as `user_last_name`,
      `company`.`title` AS `company_name`,
      `category`.`title` AS `category_name`,
      `town`.`name` AS `town_name`
  FROM 
    `rewards`
  LEFT JOIN `users` ON (`users`.`id` = `rewards`.`id_user`)
  LEFT JOIN `company` ON (`company`.`id` = `rewards`.`id_company`)
  LEFT JOIN `category` ON (`category`.`id` = `company`.`id_category`)
  LEFT JOIN `town` ON (`town`.`id` = `company`.`id_town`)
  WHERE 
      {$ВАШЕ_УСЛОВИЕ}
  GROUP BY
    `rewards`.`id`
```

попробуйте такой вариант, запрос выведет отзывы о компаниях.

Если

```
$ВАШЕ_УСЛОВИЕ = '`rewards`.`id_company` = 1'
```

то вы получите все отзывы о компании с ID 1

Answer (score -2):

Самый простой и понятный способ - это субзапросы (в таблицы region, rewards и т.д.) по каждой строчке из таблицы с компаниями. Сюда же подойдут запросы с JOIN, хотя они плохо приспособлены под масштабирование данных и для новичков менее понятны.

Наиболее оптимальный вариант - последовательный запрос данных в каждой из таблиц с последующим их сопоставлением:

1. Выполняем запрос в таблицу с компаниями. Собираем id для субзапросов.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM companies WHERE ...;
   ```
2. Выполняем субзапрос со всеми найденными ранее id в таблицу region, rewards и т.д.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM region WHERE id_town=$1 OR id_town=$2 OR ...;
   ```
3. Выполняем сопоставление данных из основной таблицы с компаниями и данных, полученных из субзапросов.

В этом случае мы не посылаем в базу множество запросов и структура SQL-данных хорошо приспособлена под будущее масштабирование.

Comment: я сделал такой запрос SELECT company.id, company.img_company, company.title, company.title_seo, users.name as u_name, users.lastname, category.title as cat_title, category.seo as cat_seo, COUNT(rewards.reiting) as rewards_num FROM company LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = company.id_user LEFT JOIN category on category.id = company.id_category LEFT JOIN rewards on rewards.id_company = company.id WHERE company.valid_status = 1  но при этом запросе выбирается только одна запись и считается общее количество строк из таблицы rewards. а мне нужно чтоб для каждой компании считалось сколько отзывов

Comment: потом переделал на SELECT company.id, company.img_company, company.title, company.title_seo, users.name as u_name, users.lastname, town.name as t_name, region.name as r_name, street.street_name, category.title as cat_title, category.seo as cat_seo, (SELECT COUNT(rewards.reiting) FROM rewards WHERE rewards.id_company = company.id) AS rewards_num FROM company, category, users, town, region, street WHERE company.id_user = users.id and company.id_category = category.id and company.id_town = town.id and company.id_region = region.id and company.id_street = street.id and company.valid_status = 1

Comment: @user190950 Вам надо к первому вашему запросу добавить в конце `group by  company.id` и count() отработает корректно, отдельно для каждой компании. Хотя для большинства СУБД надо перечислять в group by все колонки, не участвующие в агрегатных функциях, т.е. все, что у вас в списке выборки, кроме, конечно, rewards. И не увлекайтесь LEFT JOIN, слово LEFT надо писать только в том случае если вы точно знаете ради чего вы его написали (т.е. если в правой таблице может отсутствовать запись и вы это осознаете и понимаете что эти записи вам нужны)

Comment: Это в очень высоконагруженных системах стоит вместо JOIN выбирать отдельно. точнее даже не так, в таких системах наверняка таблица регионов должна быть в кеше и названия дергаются от туда. А вот выполнять в такой системе запрос вида `select x from tab where Z=1 OR Z=2 OR ...` я бы не стал ни в коем случае, большинство СУБД не умеет оптимизировать OR и получим full scan с кучей сравнений. Нормальные СУБД при JOIN умеют один раз брать записи по индексу в подклеиваемом справочнике, что в итоге будет быстрее. Особенно интересно в этом подходе будет выглядеть получение количеств по компаниям ...